# Dynamic load python package using its path

Tags: python

I need my script to be able to load some python package with all its modules so I can exec the modules and all the imports inside will work, e.g.
I have this structure

```
Package/suc_package/file1
Package/suc_package/file2
```

Inside file 1 there is an import of file 2 like this

```
from Package.suc_package import file2
```

So I need to be able to exec file1 without getting an exception that there is no such module `Package.suc_package`

I am expecting to get an absolute path of a folder and be able to exec all the modules inside of it

Comment: Is `Package` actually a package? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: If it helps: [How can I import a module dynamically given the full path?](/q/67631/4518341)

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [How to import the class within the same directory or sub directory?](/q/4142151/4518341)

Comment: When you say "exec", do you really mean that? as in, use `exec` to run the code in the current namespace? Why not just import? Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Comment: As long as `sys.path` contains the directory in which `Package` lives, there should be no problem. E.g. `PYTHONPATH=. python3 Package/suc_package/file1`.